# How do I get selected value from drop down box in Perl CGI

Tags: html, forms, perl, cgi, param

I am populating the drop down menu from database. And when I submit the form I am getting empty string in selected option. Here's my code any help will be appreciated. I have selected the first option as default any help.

```
print "<br>Name: <select>";
while ( my ($name) = fetchrow_array() ) {
    if ($name eq "Somethinge") {
        print "<option value=\"$name\" selected>" . $name . "</option>\n";
    }else {
        print "<option value=\"$name\">" . $name . "</option>\n";
        }
}
print "</select>";
```

I am getting the value using below but its returning empty whatever I select.

```
my $Name = param('name');
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `name="client_name"` in the select tag.

You probably ought to be escaping the client name in the value attribute (though for United Dynacare it isn't necessary).  Using a library to generate your HTML (for instance, [`CGI`](https://metacpan.org/module/CGI#CREATING-A-POPUP-MENU)) would have helped with both of these things.

Comment: Can you explain little bit on using library to generate html since it is very slow. To populate 1000 options its taking me over 1 minute.

Comment: that's pretty weird.  can you start a new question for that, showing what you are doing and explaining what you want for the output?