# Populating drop-down list from MySQL using Perl

Tags: html, mysql, perl

I am trying to populate the drop-down list from mysql data and got the solution from [Populating a Drop-Down list using DBI](http://forums.devshed.com/perl-programming-6/populating-a-drop-down-list-from-a-mysql-database-122793.html) and
[How do I get selected value from drop down box in Perl CGI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15095511/how-do-i-get-selected-value-from-drop-down-box-in-perl-cgi)

I have following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use DBI;
use Data::Dumper;
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
my $dbh = DBI->connect();
my @tables=$dbh->selectcol_arrayref('select TABLE_NAME from 1009_table_list order by TABLE_NAME');
print Dumper@tables; #this dumper is giving results
print qq[
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form id="upload-form"><table>
<tr><td>Table Name:</td><td><select name="tbname">
];
print Dumper@tables; # this dumper is not printing anything
foreach my $table(@tables)
{
print qq "<option value=\"$table\">" . $table . "</option>";
}
print qq[
</select>
</td></tr>
</table></form></body>
</html>
];
```

At second comment in code I am not able to get the value of @tables for the drop-list.
Why?

Comment: Could you show us the result of Dumper (or a part of it if it's too long)?

Comment: `ctrl+u` in browser to see second dumper? Besides, `print qq{<option value="$table">$table</option>};`

Comment: @M42 the dumper is `$VAR1 = [ 'ABSTRACT-ACCOUNT-CURRENT', 'CHALLAN-INVOICE', 'CLEARANCE-DETAIL-FOR-INTER-UNIT-TRANSFERS', 'CLEARANCE-DETAILS', 'DETAILS-OF-CENVAT-CREDIT-TAKEN-UTILIZED', 'HEADER-DATA', 'OTHER-PAYMENTS', 'PAID', 'RECEIPT-DETAILS-OF-INTERMEDIATE-GOODS-RECEIVEDS', 'SELF-ASSESSMENT-MEMORANDUM' ]; `

Comment: @mpapec yes its showing the dumper but how to get it into drop down...its not working. The printqq corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`selectcol_arrayref` returns array ref, so:

```
my $tables = $dbh->selectcol_arrayref('select TABLE_NAME from 1009_table_list order by TABLE_NAME');
```

---

```
foreach my $table (@$tables) {
  print qq{<option value="$table">$table</option>};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`my @tables=$dbh->selectcol_arrayref('select TABLE_NAME from 1009_table_list order by TABLE_NAME');`

returns an array_ref, in order to use it, you have to dereference it:

```
my $tables=$dbh->selectcol_arrayref('select TABLE_NAME from 1009_table_list order by TABLE_NAME');
foreach my $table (@$tables) {
    print qq~<option value="$table">$table</option>~;
}
```

Comment: you could dereference `my @tables=@{$dbh->selectcol_arrayref}` so everything else stays in place.